# Email won't list correctly in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, email

I currently have some code i need to workout, i have the correct code in the form which is fine, however i am currently using EOD and need to put that information in there within a table to email to the specified address. The code adds a row for inputting data, made of 5 input boxes, then when the user clicks submit regardless of how many rows they have added 4 or 400 it needs to email the specific address with all that information. Can someone help me with the email side of the form, i have the code working for adding the rows which is demonstrated on fiddle.

I want it to do to another page so you will notice, that the form is submitted "send" this is a page on my website where the email side of the code needs to be put together.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {

            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);

            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
            if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 1) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            }


        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }

</SCRIPT>

<div id="addbutton"><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow('datatable')"></div>
<div id="delbutton"><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('datatable')"></div>

<table id="datatable">
<tr>
    <td>
        <select class="styled-select" name="credit_type[]">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="creditbox" type="text" name="credit_production[]" placeholder="Production"/></td>
    <td><input class="creditbox" type="text" name="credit_role[]" placeholder="Role"/></td>
    <td><input class="creditbox" type="text" name="credit_director[]" placeholder="Director"/></td>
    <td><input class="creditbox" type="text" name="credit_company[]" placeholder="Company"/></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This is the PHP code, everything i have listed works.. however!

This is currently what i have for code in send.php which is where my form will be sent to i have everything else set up but the problem i have is where '...' is thats where i need $count to be however the code is not working, when placed there? Its needs to be in EOD as its going to submitted and sent via email.

```
<?php 

$emailSubject = 'Email';
$webMaster = 'email@webdomain.com';

/* Gathering Data Variables */

$credit_type = $_POST['credit_type'][$i];
$credit_production = $_POST['credit_production'][$i];
$credit_role = $_POST['credit_role'][$i];
$credit_director = $_POST['credit_director'][$i];
$credit_company = $_POST['credit_company'][$i];

$count = count($_REQUEST['credit_type']);
for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    echo '<div class="whitespacetable">';
    echo '<table class="forms">';
    echo '<tr><td width="100px">Type</td><td>' . $_REQUEST['credit_type'][$i] . '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td width="100px">Production</td><td>'. $_REQUEST['credit_production'][$i] . '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td width="100px">Role</td><td>'. $_REQUEST['credit_role'][$i] . '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td width="100px">Director</td><td>'. $_REQUEST['credit_director'][$i] . '</td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td width="100px">Company</td><td>'. $_REQUEST['credit_company'][$i] . '</td></tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';
}

$bodymain = <<<EOD
<div class="section"><strong>Section 4 - Credits</strong></div>
...
EOD;
?>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Can't you just put `{$count}` inside the EOD?

Comment: No unfortunately doesn't work, basically the code works, basically i need to put the table where ... is, but its not working :/ I've tried {$count}

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this:

```
$bodymain = <<<EOD
<div class="section"><strong>Section 4 - Credits</strong></div>
...
EOD;
```

With:

```
$bodymain = '<div class="section"><strong>Section 4 - Credits</strong></div>';
$bodymain .= $count; //$count was appended after Section 4 - Credits
echo $bodymain; //If you want to check it for debugging.
```

You can also do....

```
$bodymain = '<div class="section"><strong>Section 4 - Credits</strong></div>';
$bodymain .= $count;
$bodymain .= <<<EOD
<!--- More HTML --->
EOD;
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work, their is more to the bodyadmin code so therefore this doesn't work :/

Comment: What really do u want to put in the bodymain variable? Is it all HTML?

Comment: Can you tell me what did you do?